# monitor traffic to and from my pc

Tags: ajax, networking, network-programming

1. I want to see each url request made my by browser.
2. I want to see the url requests made by ajax.

Which software should I use? Some java code would also help.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on superuser.com?

Comment: @kitchen It depends... I watch my http requests while coding ajax for websites all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or if you need to "go deep" (as their web page says), you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: +1 for Wireshark. That was my first thought too until I realized it was overkill for the question.

Comment: @Gabriel:  Agreed, but it's nice to have it in your tool kit just in case. :)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has a great plugin called [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) that I think will get you what you are looking for.  I'm not positive on the AJAX part of the question, but it's worth a shot.  I consider LiveHTTPHeaders to be an indispensable tool for anyone doing web development.

Comment: LiveHTTPHeaders is excellent. I have used it a lot. If I just need to see the individual files without any of the details, I prefer FireBug's net panel or Google Page Speed Activity panel. Both of those have nice graphical colored displays.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/net.gif))</sub>

Otherwise use [Wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/](http://www.wireshark.org/) if you want the swiss army knife of network capture tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of great programs out there that will do this. My answer would really depend on what you are trying to do.

Adding an HTTP proxy that logs requests will easily do the job.

You can also leverage browser plugins such as FireBug and Google's Page Speed to see the requests fly in realtime.

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand where do you want to see the traffic. But if what you mean is browser and if you are using Firefox then [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will come handy.

Answer (score 0):

So many great extensions for Firefox that'll give you that info:

- Firebug
- PageSpeed
- LiveHTTPHeaders

You could also try using the developer tools in Safari or Chrome if you're not a Firefox fan.

If you use IE... why are you using IE? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Any personal proxy will do. Fiddler was already suggested.
2. For Firefox I would use the TamperData plugin.